# Would changing of all canonical URLs from relative to absolute temporarily hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, canonical-url

Would it make any significant temporary problems to change all canonical URLs from relative to absolute?

Comment: Link rel canonical **must** be absolute.  [Google says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066): "Avoid errors: use absolute paths rather than relative paths with the rel=canonical link element."  Using relative URLs in canonical would hurt SEO.

Comment: Yes, but does changing links have a _temporary_ negative effect? Just like for example moving from http to https.

Comment: As in you had been using relative canonicals, realized it was a mistake and need to change it?

Comment: For example, yes.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Regarding Google’s "Avoid errors": I think that this is just an advice, not a requirement. Per the `canonical` RFC, [relative URL references are fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458856/1591669) (like with any other link type), and one of the other answers quotes Google’s old documentation, which said this, too (tl;dr: both ways are possible, but the absolute way is recommended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If search engines indexed exactly the same URLs which you now want to provide as absolute references, there is no reason to assume that the change affects anything. It’s just a different way to [specify URL references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458856/1591669) in the `href` attribute, but the end result is the same.

However, if your current relative references result in absolute URLs different from those which you intend to specify now, indexed URLs might change. Examples when this could be the case:

- if you have specified a `base` element (it only affects relative references)
- if your site is accessible from different hostnames (with `www` and without `www`, via HTTPS and via HTTP, multiple domains, …)